# Android - Make a custom view selectable in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android

So I have a ListView, presenting custom Views (each with an image + text).
I want those views to have a different appearance when the user selects them. (with an overlay, but for now I try to make it work with just a background)

If I inflate a row with `Android.Resource.Layout.TestListItem`, it works, the cell shows the selected state when I click.

However, I try to get a similar effect with my custom layout, and I can't get it to work. Is something missing ?

I have this view layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/rowbackground">

... (textview and image)
```

and rowbackground.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_a" />
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_b" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_c" />
<item android:state_selected="false" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_d"/>
</selector>
```

But the only two that work are the "default" and the "pressed" states. Not the "selected" one. (I tried also checked, as I see it in some samples)

How can I make my custom-layout View selectable ?

Comment: why android.R.layout.test_list_item works is probably because the test_list_item is a TextView and your layout is a LinearLayout,

Comment: trye adding android:focusable="false" to your LinearLayout, or just use a TextView as your layout and use its attribut leftDrawable to show an image to the left of the TextView it is more convenient when you have just a TextView and an Image.

Comment: Thanks. Probably so, but what is it that makes the TextView selectable and not the LinearLayout ? I tried to add android:focusable="false" but it didn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok actually, to handle the "selected" state in a listview, you have to use the **activated** selector (`android:state_activated`), like:

```
<item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_dep" />
```

Of course that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. But why, it's so straightforward ? Thanks android

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in ListView `android:background="@drawable/rowbackground"` and don't remove this line from Custom layout.